# cache coherency in application

Tags: multithreading, caching, concurrency

cache coherency protocol is well known in multi-cores context which is in the hardware low-level, however, we will meet the similar case in the application domain. Recently, I am working on a project which has two threads updating shared objects.

1. UI thread is responsible for
   displaying and updating(via users
   action) objects.
2. Background replication thread
   periodically updates the shared
   objects if something is changed by
   other users.

since we have lots of objects(50,000~100,000), each thread have to copy part of objects into its own buffer, updating the shared objects is serial.

1. UI thread will not update object
   each time when users update.
2. Background replication thread will
   update objects immediately once
   changes are found and then notify UI
   thread to refresh.

So this brings the question, if there is a object updated by two threads, how is conflict sovled? Is there any common idiom to handle this case?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to handle this is to use a mutex. The UI locks the mutex before it reads the value, then unlocks it afterwards. The background thread locks the mutex before it updates the value, then unlocks it afterwards.

You can have the update thread send a notification message to the UI telling it to reread the shared object, as you suggested.

Comment: so after ui threading re-read, what is the next step that ui thread should do? is there any example to refer?